# Ошибка при миграции с sqlite на postgresql django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-model

При запуске `py manage.py migrate --run-syncdb` или просто `migrate` возникает ошибка

> django.db.utils.DataError: ОШИБКА:  значение "10000000000" вне диапазона для типа integer
> LINE 1: ALTER TABLE "shopapp_products" ADD COLUMN "price" numeric(10...

**models.py**

```py
class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='Название')
    product_code = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True,
    validators=[MaxValueValidator(9999999)], verbose_name='Код продукта')
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описание товара',
    default='Тестовое описание товара', blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Цена за единицу')
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Categories', related_name='products')
    image = models.ImageField(null=True)
```

1. Помогите решить эту проблему
2. Объясните пожалуйста **откуда** он взял значение в 10 миллиардов и зачем оно нужно

Comment: Не 10 миллионов, а 10 миллиардов. Проверьте код своих миграций

Comment: Ну или если в миграциях точно нет ничего ценного, то тупо удалите их и пересоздайте заново, авось поможет (и базу в postgresql тоже заново пересоздайте)

Answer (score 0):

Решил удалением всех миграций до этого